# Find empty cell, add all the cells above, and place sum in the empty cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and I've been working on a VBA project that needs to find the empty cell and add all the cells above that empty cell and also place the sum on it. I tried finding the right code for it but no luck. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Here's the part of the data in the project:

[image: jhvkkjhvghvj]

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not very clear about this _find the empty cell and add all the cells above that empty cell and also place the sum on it_ - add all values from above the empty cell, and also add a sum?!? also, are you referring the the cells containing "#N/A" as empty? what about the top empty cells, with no values above them?

Comment: Yes, I'm pertaining to the #N/A as the empty cell. I need to find the #N/A/empty cell then add all the values before it ($27,500 to 10,501.50) and place the sum to the #N/A/empty cell and vice versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your question is not clear. The logic of my code is

> Looping all row between **startRow** and **lastRow**
> And find blank cell(#N/A).
> If found, adding values of all above cell from that cell and set total to that cell.
> But the adding is quarterly. And If continuous cells are found, set 0.
>
> Means:
> If startRow = 1 and lastRow = 11, blank cell are 5, 10 and 11.
> So, total value from row 5 cell is adding of above 4 cell(1+2+3+4) and
> total value from row 10 cell is also adding of above 4 cell(6+7+8+9).
> And total value from row 11 cell is 0. Don't know logic to do.

I think that I give an right answer. I already tested the code. It perfectly work for me. If it is not for you, let me know. Here the code:

```
Public Sub findTotal()

    Dim startRow, lastRow As Long
    Dim row, innerStart As Long
    
    With Sheets("Budget")
    
        'Set start row
        startRow = 1
        innerStart = startRow
        
        'last row must be last blank row for add all cell above from that
        lastRow = 35
    
        'Looping all row between startRow and lastRow
        For row = startRow To lastRow Step 1
        
            'Loop until blank
            If .Range("N" & row).Text = "#N/A" Then
            
                If row - startRow > 0 And row <> innerStart Then
            
                    'Set total of above cell to blank cell
                    .Range("N" & row) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range("N" & row - 1, "N" & innerStart))
                    
                    'Set next start row for adding next blank cell
                    innerStart = row + 1
                
                Else
                
                    'Set 0 for continuous cells
                    .Range("N" & row) = 0

                    'Here, if you want to set above total, you can use as follow:
                    '.Range("N" & row) = .Range("N" & row - 1)
                
                End If
            
            End If
            
        Next row
    
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello. I tried the code. A Runtime Error 13 appeared. Type Mismatch. On the  Do While .Range("N" & row) <> "" part

Comment: On the 9th line:  Do While .Range("N" & row) <> ""

Comment: Ok, what is your input data sheet. Can you show me? One things is that you need to change `Sheet1` to your sheet name. Is it changed?

Comment: You mean the Excel file?

Comment: SHEET Name...not file name. Excel sheet name should be set at this line `Sheets("sheetname")`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85079/discussion-between-nicolas-and-z9z9z9).